# Python: select rows with changed values

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Suppose we have 2 dataframes, A and B, which are given as follows:

A = [image]                     B =[image]

And can be computed with the following code:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['A','A1',1], ['B','B1' ,3], ['C', 'C2', 5], ['D','D1',7], ['E','E4',9], ['F','F1',11]], columns=['Label1','Label2' , 'Value'])
B = pd.DataFrame([['A','A1', 1], ['B','B1',4], ['C','C2',3], ['D','D2',7], ['E','E4',8], ['F','F2',11]], columns=['Label1','Label2' ,'Value'])
```

In this example, the labels are placed on the same indices in both matrices, but this need not be the case.

I want to select the rows of B where the 'Value' has changed compared to the corresponding value in matrix A (i.e. same label1 and label2). Even better: would it be possible to separately select rows where the value has increased and decreased?

I know it's possible by simply going through the entries one by one, but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way?

Desired output for rows that have increased in value:

```
[B  B1 4]
```

Desired output for rows that have decreased in value:

```
[C C2 5]
[E E4 8]
```

Comment: Could you add the expected output? For example, how would you like to treat rows where labels are different?

Comment: Could you post your desired output? I'm not totally sure what you do when `label1` and `label2` are the same but `value` is different, or when `label1` and `label2` are the same and `value` is the same

Comment: I've included the desired output, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with rows which have labels in both dataframes you can join dataframes and then compare the 2 columns:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['A','A1',1], ['B','B1' ,3], ['C', 'C2', 5], ['D','D1',7], ['E','E4',9], ['F','F1',11]], columns=['Label1','Label2' , 'ValueA'])
B = pd.DataFrame([['A','A1', 1], ['B','B1',4], ['C','C2',3], ['D','D2',7], ['E','E4',8], ['F','F2',11]], columns=['Label1','Label2' ,'ValueB'])

df = pd.merge(A, B, on = ['Label1', 'Label2'])
df

    Label1 Label2  ValueA  ValueB
0      A     A1       1       1
1      B     B1       3       4
2      C     C2       5       3
3      E     E4       9       8

df['Comparison'] = np.where(df['ValueA'] > df['ValueB'], 'A>B', np.where(df['ValueA'] < df['ValueB'], 'A<B', 'A=B'))

df

  Label1 Label2  ValueA  ValueB Comparison
0      A     A1       1       1        A=B
1      B     B1       3       4        A<B
2      C     C2       5       3        A>B
3      E     E4       9       8        A>B
```